# Change function options on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slider

What I’m trying to do is, when the user scrolls down the page the timeout option in the slider changes to 0. Then if the user scrolls back to the top of the page it changes back to 4000. I tried it a bunch of times using on() with an if/else statement but couldn’t get it to work.

Any advice much appreciated.

```
$('#slides').before('<div id="counter">').maximage({
    cycleOptions: {
        pager: '#counter',
        timeout: 4000,
        after:function(){
            $('#caption').html(this.title);
        }
    }
});
```

Apologies, [this](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/) is the slider plugin I’m using.

Comment: What `maximage` plugin are you using (please link its docs), does it provide a facility to change options? Also please post the code you've tried for the scroll event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define it as a global variable

```
var timeVal = 4000;
```

And then change it whenever you want to

```
$(selector).someEvent(function(){
   timeVal = 500;      // Your new value.
});
```

And use that variable.

```
$('#slides').before('<div id="counter">').maximage({
cycleOptions: {
    pager: '#counter',
    timeout: timeVal,
    after:function(){
        $('#caption').html(this.title);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: But the variable will be evaluated only once?

Comment: In that case put the $('#slides').. in a function and pass the variable as a parameter. Then call that function when you want to do stuff.

Comment: Probably the OP doesn't want to call it multiple times? Also it would need modifications because otherwise multiple `<div id="counter">`s would be created.

Comment: @Bergi You are right about that. I was trying to answer best from the given info. Mainly the have dynamic value for timeout part. But yea, this would definitely need modification for the way the OP is going to actually use it.

Comment: I put timeVal inside an if/else statement which watched for page scrolling but console was telling me there was no timeVal which was referenced in the cycleOptions.